# How do I add new users so the drives are mapped upon login?

Tags: windows-server-2008, users, mappeddrive, mapping, drive

In an existing Windows Server 2008 domain the users added by professional IT administrators automatically mapped drives when they logged onto any office machine.

The new users I've added, however, don't appear to be mapping drives as expected.

My process was as follows:

1. Start `Active Directory Users and Computers`
2. Under `[mydomain]` under `User Accounts` click `Create a new user in the current container`
3. Enter the user information and finish that dialog/wizard.
4. Right click the user, select `Add to a group...` and add them to the relevant folder groups and email distribution lists.

While the users have access to the paths, the drives are not mapped as is automatically done with existing accounts. I've gone through the `Properties...` and all the settings appear to be the same, including `Connect client drives at logon` being checked under the `Environment` tab.

Comment: Do you have roaming profiles?

Comment: @GregL Yes, but I'm not sure that it's operating on the new users, let me check into that.

Comment: If you have roaming profiles, the old users probably manually mapped the shares and checked the "reconnect at logon" box.

Comment: @GregL When I was added as a user I had a set of drives already mapped for me.  Later I needed access to a new resource, and the IT crew altered the user account settings on the domain controller remotely, then asked me to log out and back in - the new drives were mapped automatically, I didn't add any mappings, and they never remotely logged into my computer.  Further, the Group Policy Object DriveMappings does appear to have rules for all the drives that everyone has mapped, and everyone has the same paths and drive letters for the resources they have access to. I don't think it's manual...

Comment: @GregL Notably, the roaming profile is working correctly for the new users, they do have a mapped user drive and all their documents, etc are on the server as it is with others.

Comment: Then it looks like you're going to need to figure out why the GPO's DriveMappings aren't working for this user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find out *how* the drives are assigned. The most common way would be a logon script:

- Right-click a user
- Properties - Profile - Logon Script

**or** another way would be with Group Policy Preferences. So there should be a Group Policy for this purpose somewhere in your AD.

If you found out how the drives are mapped you are able to take the appropriate steps on how to add new users...

Comment: There is no script on the profile of users it is working for.  Under the group policy management console I see there's a `DriveMappings` Policy Object which appears to have a `Replace` action to map a drive to a path when a user is part of a particular security group.  These users are members of this group, though, so I'm still unsure what the issue is.

Comment: Check if you have a group policy where `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Logon\Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon` is enabled. Also can you add some screenshots?

Comment: While I see a few policy objects with `Administrative Templates` in the `Computer Configuration` section, none appear to affect `System\Logon` - they go over remote assistance, windows update, network firewall, and security.

Comment: I think it's a best practice to have this enabled. Also have you verified that this GPO is applied at the client? Are these Windows 8 clients?

Comment: How would I check to see if it's applied?

Comment: Start - run `rsop.msc`. This is an MMC Snap-In where you can see what settings are applied on a client.